# Unit Test code coverage problem

Tags: apex, unit-test

[image]Here this is the class:

```
public class relatedList 
{

    public account acc{set;get;}
    public contact con{set;get;}    
    public string accname{set;get;}
    public void getdata() {
      acc=[select name,id from account where name=:accname];
      con=[select id,name,title,email,phone from contact where account.id=:acc.id limit 1];
    }

}
```

Here is Test Class which covers only 83% why not 100%? Showing error like list has no rows. Help me to resolve this.

```
@isTest

public class relatedList_TC

{

    static testMethod void testMthd()
    {
        relatedList rl=new relatedList();
        account a=new account(name='xxx');
        contact c=new contact(lastname='yyy',accountid=a.id);
        rl.getData();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the SOQL is filtering by `accname`, you need to set that field in your unit test. You also need to insert the objects in the test so they can be queried. So overall:

```
static testMethod void testMthd()
{
    account a=new account(name='xxx');
    insert a;
    contact c=new contact(lastname='yyy',accountid=a.id);
    insert c;

    relatedList rl=new relatedList();
    rl.accname = 'xxx';
    rl.getData();
    System.assertEquals(a.Id, rl.acc.Id);
    System.assertEquals(c.Id, rl.con.Id);
}
```

You should also add a "limit 1" to the Account query in your relatedList class because in production there could easily be multiple Accounts of the same name.

Comment: Thank you for replay but accname is not a variable in test class,one more thing problem @Contact list

Comment: @Krish25 In your test method set `rl.accname = 'xxx';`.

Comment: @Krish25 By having `rl.` in front of `accname` the test code is setting a field in an instance of relatedList. And you are right that isn't enough change to get your test to work: the Account and Contact need to be inserted into the database as well as created in memory. See the updated code in the answer.

Comment: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: r1.accname ,i am getting this error.

Comment: @Krish25 - it is `rl.accname` not `r1.accname` (letter l not number 1)

Comment: @Eric,Thanks a lot dude.one Small doubt without writing Assert statements also its covering 100%,then what is the need of Assert Statements.

Comment: @Krish to ensure the correct outcome. Just because you cover 100% does not mean it produces the correct outcome. You need to test the outcome which is the purpose of the asserts

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert your records within the test class, and then they will be available to the SOQL query:

```
static testMethod void testMthd()
{
    relatedList rl=new relatedList();
    account a=new account(name='xxx');
    insert a;

    contact c=new contact(lastname='yyy',accountid=a.id);
    insert c;

    rl.getData();
}
```

Comment: Still same coverage 83%,not covering Contact query.help me to cover that query.